# a cracking challenge in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, challenge-response

hello guys i just want help to understand that algorithm i understand bitwise xor and % operators but i cant understand whats happening exactly i dont want **the flag** i want to underatand what to do to get the flag & thanks

```
PASS = input('Enter the Flag: ')
KEY = 'I know, you love decrypting Byte Code !'
I = 5
SOLUCE = [57, 73, 79, 16, 18, 26, 74, 50, 13, 38, 13, 79, 86, 86, 87]
KEYOUT = []
for X in PASS:
    KEYOUT.append((ord(X) + I ^ ord(KEY[I])) % 255)
    I = (I + 1) % len(KEY)

if SOLUCE == KEYOUT:
    print('You Win')
else:
    print('Try Again !')
```

any help !

Comment: This looks like a combination of [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) (XOR on the flag and key characters) and [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) (shift by `I`) so start your read there...

Comment: i am asking about whats really happening in the for loop and how to reverse i tried chr but not working

Comment: That's really easy task, I have trouble hinting without giving complete solution out. Please, elaborate what you tried and where you failed. Giving complete solution without solid evidence of your attempts is frowned upon on SO

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  use a debugger or a lots of prints to display the steps to get behind what the code does... - like "what is ord(X) . what is I ^ ord(...) etc

Comment: Bruteforce in this case is surely an option. And it doesn't require Ruby. ;)

Comment: @Seer.The Lets see your solution then...

Answer (score 0):

There will be how I thought about this problem and complete solution.

1. Notice `len(KEYOUT) == len(PASS) == len(SOLUCE)`
2. Notice that there's no dependency between symbols
3. So all you need is find such `X` that `(ord(X) + I ^ ord(KEY[I])) % 255)` is equal to corresponding element in `SOLUCE`

   ```
   FLAG = []
   for part in SOLUCE:
       for ord_X in range(0, 256):
           current_try = (ord_X + I ^ ord(KEY[I])) % 255
           if current_try == part:
               FLAG.append(chr(ord_X))
               break
       else:
           print("fiasco")  # if you aren't sure task is solvable. Not necessary line
       I = (I + 1) % len(KEY)
   ```

Validating is trivial.